# Angular sites redirects to different site/domain with json data

Tags: json, angular, redirect, cookies, cross-domain

We have site a.com, based on user selection it generates json, now user need to redirects to site B.com
to do some more reporting (centralised site for multiple departments separate UI) I need to pass that json to site B.com and on final reporting some json will go back to a.com
(Sso is there for both sites, developing in angular 16)
Iframe way we don’t wanna use.
Any standard way to achieve this architecture?

Any reference link or sample code will help

Sample code or reference link for angular or js

Comment: How much data are we talking about? And do you have a backend..?

Comment: Its jaon large data the url has limit for parameters so that isnt an option